# ORA-06550 when trying to run stored procedure in oracle c#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

```
 using (var command = new OracleCommand(sqlText, oraConnection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
                {
                    command.BindByName = true;
                    var parameters = command.Parameters;
                    parameters.Clear();
                    parameters.Add("p_date", OracleDbType.Date, ParameterDirection.Input).Value = DateTime.Now;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
```

Here is my code in VS15. I am trying to execute a stored procedure and pass in my only parameter as a date.

```
create or replace procedure cwi_pat_deductions_export
(
       :p_date date
)
is

  v_count number;
```

This is the beginning of the stored proc. I am getting Oracle Error : ORA-06550 at line 1 col 7 (so right after the word "CREATE"). I am not a sql dev by trade, so I am struggling to see where the error is. I dont feel like it is on my end (the c# side) but it very well could be (our sql developer insists that it must be a problem on my end, as the stored proc compiles and runs fine in PlSql Developer).

are you not allowed to start stored procs with Create or replace? i thought that was standard.

Comment: What is the value of `sqlText`?  Are you trying to call the stored procedure or create it?

Comment: sqltex is the stored procedure

Comment: also using as instead of is did not work to whoever suggested it (but i appreciate the try)

Comment: Is sqltext is the stored procedure **name** or the stored procedure lines of code?

Comment: If you're trying to execute the stored procedure sqlText should be only the stored procedure name (cwi_pat_deductions_export) not the whole stored procedure definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't pass the full `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE ...` text of the procedure when you want to call it.  The point of the procedure being *stored* is that this is already stored in the database.

If you want to call the stored procedure, the `sqlText` parameter should be just the stored procedure name, `cwi_pat_deductions_export`.  If that doesn't work, and you get an `invalid identifier` error, try preceding the name with the owner of the stored procedure, for example `some_schema.cwi_pat_deductions_export`.

Comment: that seems to have solved that issue at least. Learning something new every day.

Comment: Now I am getting "Not all variables bound" when i change sqltext to be:

Comment: "CW.cwi_cwi_pat_deductions_export(:p_date)"

Comment: @JacobAlley: I wrote that 'the `sqlText` parameter should be just the stored procedure name'.  It doesn't matter how many parameters the stored procedure takes (if any), `sqlText` is always just the stored procedure name (with schema prefixed if necessary).  You don't put the parameter names in the `sqlText`. So, frankly, I'm not surprised that when you make your change it doesn't work.

Comment: yea i just wasnt sure how to pass in the parameter to the stored procedure, but it seems to be working fine now....thank you for your helpt hough